# Isosceles triangle and inscribed circle

Tags: geometry, triangles

If the center of the inscribed circle in a isosceles triangle is dividing the height of the triangle in a proportion 5 : 12, what's the lenght of the legs if the base is 50cm?

Comment: What have you tried? See [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Well, I tried using the general formula for triangles using height, however it didn't lead me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us draw a picture for the story:

[image: Stackexchange problem 3683964]

Here $AB$ is the base with the mid point $O$ (placed in the origin of the axes in the picture), and $C$ is on the side bisector of $AB$. The triangle from the $OP$ is $\Delta ABC$, and we know that it has the incenter $I$ delimiting the proportion $5:12$ on the height $CO$. First of all, the "samller part" is $IO$, because $O$ is the biggest angle in $\Delta CAO$. So we have explicitly, also using the angle bisector theorem in this triangle:
$$
\frac{5}{12}
=
\frac{IO}{IC}
=
\frac{AO}{AC}
=
\frac{AB/2}{AC}
=
\frac{25}{AC}
\ .
$$
This gives $AC=60$.

$\square$

The picture was drawn using scale one to five.

Answer (score 1):

If we let $x$ be the proportionality constant, then it follows that the height of the triangle is $5x+12x=17x$ and the inradius is $5x$. The area of the triangle, $$A=\frac 12 \times 50 \times 17x$$ Calculated [another way](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Area_of_Triangle_in_Terms_of_Inradius), $$A=rs =5x\times \frac{2l+50}{2}$$ Equating the two expressions gives $l=60$ cm.